# How to upload Image from Local Drive in Angular Markdown Editor

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, markdown

I want to upload local image to Angular Markdown Editor (v2.0.0)
Currently its only allowing me to attach it through published webserver url.
Can someone please help me.

[image: Example_image]

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: No Himanshu. Not yet